# Styling issue on header background with new nav bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Looks like the new nav bar adjusted the header height, causing some clip with the transparent background image and the fill used. Pretty self-explanatory, should be easily fixable.

[image]

Close up from [duplicate question](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2637/102).

[image]

Comment: Came here with a screen capture to post the same question! Good man batter.cord!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have this fixed locally - we will likely be deploying the fix in the next few hours.

Current revision is `rev 2017.10.11.27368`, so if that changes, the fix is in.

Answer (score 1):

I checked this and they might need to set background image by -2px to fix it. Initially it was -38px.

[image]