# Ugly pixels at bottom of new top-bar

Tags: bug

The new [top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301845/144041) is here and we seem to have picked up some rogue pixels on the bottom of the header image.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]