# Styles broken again?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Same issue as [Styling issue on header background with new nav bar](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2636/styling-issue-on-header-background-with-new-nav-bar), seems to have regressed. Thought it was just my adblockers at first.

[image]

Comment: Yep. It's broken for me too.

Comment: Yes, Its broken maybe some old code overwritten :).

Comment: Pretty sure this was related to the update to the new nav bar as part of some of the changes made a while back, but I'm surprised it still isn't fixed, does anyone have a reason for this?

Comment: thanks for reporting, i'm looking into this right now...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks again for reporting. This was caused by some changes in *top bar* (that black bar on top of the page). Anyway, fix for this bug is waiting in repo and should be up on site in couple hours.